# How to achieve string interpolation while appending html inside a div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-append

Might be a silly question but here it is.
I am trying to insert some html inside my div based on data received from my backing java controller. It all works fine but I am not aware how to interpolate strings from the data I receive into the paragraph tag of my jsp.

Here is the code

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = "${context}/support/ajax";
        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : url,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data, status, xhr) {

                data.forEach(function(data) {
                    if (data.userType == 'O') {
                        $( ".chats" ).append(`
                                <div class='chat-avatar'>


                                <a class='avatar' data-toggle='tooltip' href='#'
                                    data-placement='right' title='' data-original-title=''> <img
                                    src='<c:url value = '/app-assets/images/portrait/small/avatar-s-1.png'/>'
                                    alt='avatar'>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class='chat-body'>
                                <div class='chat-content'>
                                    <p>{data.comment}</p> // **This is what I want to achieve**
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                `);

                    } 

                });
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

The above ajax call works fine an I do receive data. Also, I am able to insert this html into the appropriate div element. Now I want to insert the data.comment value inside the p element .

How do I do this ?

**EDIT --1**

After using `${expression}` syntax, the `<p>` tag comes as blank  in the broswer console while clearly the value is present.

[image: dev tools]

**EDIT--2**

I don't know why but `"<p>"+d.comment+"</p>"`  is working. But not interpolation.

Comment: So close. Template strings (or template literals; the backtick version of strings) use the syntax `${expression}` to interpolate expressions. So you're just missing the `$` prepended to your current interpolation syntax :)

Comment: Note that not all browsers support template literals

Comment: When I do this  (backtick)...<p>${data.comment}</p>....(backtick)  nothing comes up on the UI. Running this on chrome.a

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using the back-tick (`) you are close to using template strings. You just need to use placeholders correctly:

```js
const data = {comment: 'The comment'};
const result = `...<p>${ data.comment }</p>...`;

console.log(result);
```

[Documentation on Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: When I do this  (backtick)...<p>${data.comment}</p>....(backtick)  nothing comes up on the UI. Running this on chrome.a

Comment: @Naxi, if you console.log(data.comment) at the beginning of the success function, is it possible the value is an empty string?

Comment: I checked and it's not. It shows the values correctly in console.log but not in template literal.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you're using the data variable for both the ajax response and the current value of data in the loop. Are you sure you're referencing the correct object?

Comment: Even if I change that to be two different variables, the result is the same.